# why does this have a extra space after the '-' in 'I-'?

Tags: python

I'm taking a class through zybooks, and the whitespace is a bit glitchy through here. I'm not sure what is causing this extra space, so any help would be appreciated.

The instructions for this:

Primary U.S. interstate highways are numbered 1-99. Odd numbers (like the 5 or 95) go north/south, and evens (like the 10 or 90) go east/west. Auxiliary highways are numbered 100-999, and service the primary highway indicated by the rightmost two digits. Thus, I-405 services I-5, and I-290 services I-90. Note: 200 is not a valid auxiliary highway because 00 is not a valid primary highway number.

Given a highway number, indicate whether it is a primary or auxiliary highway. If auxiliary, indicate what primary highway it serves. Also indicate if the (primary) highway runs north/south or east/west.

```
highway_number = int(input()) 
if highway_number == 0:
    print(highway_number, 'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
if highway_number in range(1,99+1):
     if highway_number % 2 == 0:
         print('I-',highway_number,"is primary, going east/west.")
     else:
          print('I-',highway_number,"is primary, going north/south.")
else:
  served = highway_number % 100 
  if highway_number >= 1000:
    print(highway_number,'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
  if highway_number in range(99,999+1):
     if highway_number == 200:
       print(highway_number,'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
     elif highway_number % 2 == 0:
         print('I-',highway_number,'is auxiliary, serving I-','%.f,'%served,'going east/west.')
     else:
          print('I-',highway_number,'is auxiliary, serving I-','%.f,'%served, 'going north/south.')
```

[image: Picture for reference of output]

Everything is working correctly, I just keep getting an extra space after the '-' in 'I-'.

Answer (score 7):

That is how print works. It add space between every argument. That is why

```
print(1,2,3)
```

prints `1 2 3` not `123`.

So, most of the time, you want that behavior.

That being said, you can change it

```
print(1,2,3, sep='')
```

prints `123`

In your case (not yet the solution)

```
print("I-", highway_number,"is primary, going east/west.", sep='')
```

But, see, now you get

```
I-90is primary, going east/west.
```

So, you see, yourself, you want that space. Just not everywhere. If you added `sep=''` now, you have to add explicitly the spaces you want

```
print("I-",highway_number," is primary, going east/west.", sep='')
```

Another method would be to print a f-string, in which you can insert values

```
print(f"I-{highway_number} is primary, going east/west.")
```

Or mixture of it

```
print(f"I-{highway_number}", "is primary, going east/west.")
```

Or some variants (there are many way in python to prints string containing values)

```
print("I-%d is primary, going east/west."%(highway_number,))
```

```
print("I-{} is primary, going east/west.".format(highway_number))
```

But the fastest and easiest way are f-string (they are also the most recent ones, which explain why the other exist while not being as easy and as fast. Plus others methods can do more things, but none that concern our case)

Answer (score 1):

In `print()` python if you add `,` between variables it adds a space by default.
To avoid this you can change the `,` with `+` *(change the type of variable to string for this case)*

```
print("Hi",".") # Hi .
print("Hi"+".") #Hi.
```

Alternatively, you can also use f-strings for easy management.

```
a = "."
print(f"Hi{a}") #Hi.
print("Hi{0}".format(a)) #Hi.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
print('I-',highway_number,"is primary, going east/west.", sep="")
```

To remove the added space between each item of print. `sep` is short for separator.
More detail: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: Why use sep when you could use f-strings?

Comment: I simply mean to provide them with the best technique rather than just a technique.

Comment: Both are valid, but it seems to me @zel does not know about ```f-strings```, and they are a more used and practical choice than ```sep``` and can be used in a different variety. The use of ```,``` to add a space is a bad practice, and adding a ```sep``` makes it worse. What if a space was required in one place, but not in the other

Comment: Both methods are equally valid. Note that `sep=''` method is faster! That must count for something (even if f-string are also really fast. compare to less recent methods, such as `"%d"%highway_number` or `"{}".format(highway_number)`. `sep=''` doesn't have to build a new string.

Comment: That being said, if you add a `sep=''` in your print, then you must also add the space you wanted. There are 2 implicit spaces in this print. The first one was unwanted. The second, after the number, was wanted.  So, `sep=''` is a perfectly valid way to remove the first. But then you must put back explicitly the second that is also removed. In other words, you may want to edit your answer to add a space before `"is primay..."`.

Comment: I feel ```sep``` adds unecessary confusion as spaces are to be adjusted based on whether they are wanted or not. ```f_strings``` exactly display where the space is in one look

Comment: Yeah, totally agree. I believe that @chrlg answer is the best answer here

Comment: But I also think it good to know that print will automatically add "\n" at the end of a sentence and " " between each argument --> Reading the document for print is still highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

In this line of code,

```py
print('I-',highway_number,"is primary, going east/west.")
```

the `,` adds a space. Instead, use `f-strings`

```
print(f"I-{highway_number} is primary, going east/west.")
```

Answer (score -3):

Python can be very confusing and sometimes the littlest things will change what it does. In this case, you have to change the comma next to the I- to a + sign. You then have to change the variable highway_number to a string. For example `print('I-'+ str(highway_number) + " is primary, going east/west.")`

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Good explanation,  but not the best practice and please format your code.

Comment: May I ask how to format it?

Comment: For example, the ```highway_number``` can be written like so fenced in backticks, and a new line can be added for your solution.

Comment: Thank you, is it formatted now?